# Access shows different column names than in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have a problem.
I have a stored procedure in MSSQL and when I run it in SQL, everything looks like it should, but when I link the procedure in Access Query, the name of columns changes, for example  name of the column in SQL is *1.10*, but in Access the name of column is *10*.
Maybe the mistake is in *Pivot*, or I consider of changing columns names.
Any advice?

Here is the stored procedure code:

```
select *
into ##tmp_trans
from (
      select Column1, , Format([Time], '0.00') as [Time]
      from ##tmp_type
     ) as tablee
Pivot (
       max([Time])
       for Column1 in (
       [1.1-0],[1.2-A],[1.3-B],[1.4-C],[1.5-D],[1.6-E],[1.7-F],[1.8-G],[1.9-H],[1.10-I]
       )
) as transpose
```

Comment: Access cannot work with periods in column names, at all. Period. ;) So you need to change column names.

Comment: Advise not to use any punctuation/special characters (underscore is only exception) in naming convention.